# Am I using KVM, KQemu or QEMU?

Tags: kvm, qemu

How to know which one I'm currently using when I launch a VM?

Are the QEMU and KVM project merged today? Or they still try to completely merge?

If I really understand, KVM permit to talk to all the hardware "directly" and to use VT-d, QEMU permit to traduce different architecture code, KVM permit to execute the code without any translation, KQemu permit near no translation. I'm I right?

Answer (score 2):

[KVM](https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Main_Page) is part of two projects: the Linux kernel (which hosts the kernel component of KVM), and [QEMU](https://www.qemu.org/) (which hosts the userspace component of KVM). However the kernel part of KVM [can be used without QEMU](https://lwn.net/Articles/658511/), and QEMU can be used without KVM.

KVM provides access to the virtualisation extensions available on x86 systems; it implements a hypervisor. QEMU provides emulation of the various components required to “build” a virtual PC; it can also provide instruction set translation, but that’s not used with KVM (which as you say, executes guests with no translation).

KQemu is a software-only “accelerator” (a module allowing QEMU to run code without translation on 32-bit x86 with some guests) which was rendered obsolete by KVM.

Comment: Thank you! So, today KWM can't do everything alone? Like if I want a VM with more than a CPU I need QEMU too. And QEMU alone is "garbage" in front of KVM performances, right? And finally, how do I know what I use now on the VM hosted on my computer?

Comment: Right, a VM with more than a CPU needs QEMU (or some other emulator). QEMU’s performance running x86-on-x86 is quite poor compared to the performance you get with KVM, yes, so if you can use KVM with QEMU, you might as well. Inside a VM, try looking at `/proc/cpuinfo`; I’m not sure you can easily determine whether KVM is being used from inside the VM, but outside, check `kvm_stats` and `lsof /dev/kvm`.